# I came across this code snippet in the hello android book and do not understand it

Tags: java, android

Hello I am a beginner at Java please help me explain this code snippet

```
this.game = (Game) context;
```

The member variable `game` is an object reference of class `Game` while context is passed on to the constructor

Comment: What exactly you don't understand? Please refer to a [basic tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: Can you share larger fragment of snippet to see context of this?

It means that Game class extends class of "context" variable. and it is casted to Game class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just casting `context` to `Game` and assigning it to `game` member variable.
Take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) tutorial to better understand inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

If the above compiles then it means that Game extends (either directly or not) the Context class. This is called [inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the **application context** or **activity context** which is **type cast** to Game to a variable *game* of the object which has been *implicitly* passed to the *method containing* this statement ( Hence the **this**.game ).

Answer (score 0):

A Context is a handle to the system; it provides services like resolving resources, obtaining access to databases and preferences, and so on. An android app has activities. It's like a handle to the environment your application is currently running in. The activity object inherits the Context object.

So here this.game is a member variable of class Game. The Game class is an Activity class so  inherits the Context.